# Parse id from XBRL file with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xbrl

I have an issue with scraping an XBRL file using Beautifulsoup.

Code:

```
openxbrl = open(file.file_path, 'r')
readxbrl = openxbrl.read()    
contextsoup = xbrlsoup.findAll('xbrli:context')
print(contextsoup)
```

Gives the following output (sample, there are multiple children)

```
  <xbrli:context id="context0">
     <xbrli:period>
      <xbrli:instant>
       2020-12-31
      </xbrli:instant>
     </xbrli:period>
```

I can't seem to figure out how I can parse the context id: `id="context0"` without printing the whole `contextsoup`. I tried to print the id by parsing the name:

```
 for child in contextsoup:
    pprint.pprint(child.name)
    pprint.pprint(child.find('xbrli:period'))
```

But does not give me the id

```
  'xbrli:context'
    <xbrli:period>
     <xbrli:instant>
      2020-12-31
     </xbrli:instant>
    </xbrli:period>
```

How can I parse the id without printing the whole xbrl?

Comment: what is `complete name`?

Comment: `id` is not part of `name` but it is `attribute` which you can get with `child['id']` or `child.get('id')`

Comment: child['id'] works! Thanks Furas. Did not know that the id is an attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id="context0"` is not part of the element name, it is an attribute ([BS docs on attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes))

You can access attribute values by treating a tag as a dict:

```py
for context in contextsoup:
    print(context['id'])
```

You can also find tags directly by attribute values.  The value of the `id` attribute should be unique across the document, so you can just do:

```
soup.find(id='context0')
```

You should also be aware that you are working with namespaced XML; if you are working with different XBRL reports, you can't rely on the context tags always being called `xbrli:context` because the `xbrli` bit is a document-defined prefix that provides a shorthand for a namespace URI.  I believe that Beautiful Soup 4 does have some namespace support, but I've not used it.

There is quite a lot of complexity in correctly parsing XBRL in its XML format, and I would recommend using an existing XBRL processor to do it.  One of the best ways of dealing with XBRL reports is to convert it to the newer [xBRL-JSON format](https://www.xbrl.org/Specification/xbrl-json/REC-2021-10-13/xbrl-json-REC-2021-10-13.html), and then work with it as JSON data.  There are a number of tools that can do this conversion, including the open source [Arelle](https://www.arelle.org) project.

Comment: it can be useful also `soup.find(id=True)` to get all elements with `id`

Comment: I strongly agree with the statement in the last paragraph. BS is not really the right tool for xbrl.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the suggestion of converting it into an xBRL-JSON format, I'll look into that.  @Jack What is in your opinion a better tool for parsing xbrl?

Comment: @Bob I wish I had an easy answer - xbrl is still an unholly mess. I frequent [XBRL US](https://xbrl.us/) and [the tools they provide](https://xbrl.us/home/use/xbrl-api-community/) and find them very helpful.